# How to catch/handle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Meteor on Client Side

Tags: javascript, meteor

`GET http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=y454214w6c net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Is there a simple solution for that **without** making a loop and checking continuously for an ajax response?

So is there a simple event maybe?

Comment: `http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/connections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Meteor.status()` which is reactive data source:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_status

Comment: `Meteor.status().status` was exactly what I'm searching for.